# Using form_for with "becomes" loses child association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

When building out a form that handles STI, if I use `becomes` to transform the object to its parent class, I lose the ability to use nested fields with it.

I have two models

```
class Login < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :login

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :login
end
```

I also have a few subclasses of User.

```
class Consumer < User
end

class Admin < User
end

class Agent < User
end
```

Initially I had problems with the routing, since Rails would assume that I wanted a route specific to the current class rather than the parent class, so I used `@user.becomes(User)`, which is apparently the way to handle that. For the most part it works fine, however this causes `@user.login` to disappear.

Controller

```
class Admin::UsersController < AdminController
  load_and_authorize_resource
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index
    render 'index'
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
    @user.build_login
    render 'new'
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    if @user.save
      flash[:notice] = "Account confirmation instructions sent to #{@user.login.email}"
      redirect_to new_user_path
    else
      flash.now[:error] = @user.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
      # At this point, I can confirm that @user.login still exists...
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(
        :type,
        :dealership_id,
        login_attributes: [
          :email
        ])
    end

end
```

Here's the most relevant form view bit

```
<%= simple_form_for(@user.becomes(User), html: {class: "user-form"}) do |f| %>

  <%= f.simple_fields_for :login do |l| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= l.label :email %><br />
      <%= l.email_field :email %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :type %>
    <%= f.select :type, options_for_select(current_user.types_can_create), include_blank: "- Select -", class: "form-control", id: "select_type" %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Register" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The text field for `:email` doesn't display because `@user.login` is now `nil`. Is this expected behavior when using `becomes`?

Answer (score 1):

Having only used [`becomes`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/becomes) once before, I can only attest to my scant experience -- whenever you use it, it essentially invokes a new instance of the class.

I'm not sure as to the specifics, but the bottom line is that I would surmise that your `@user.becomes(User)` is overriding `@user.build_login`...

> Returns an instance of the specified klass with the attributes of the current record.

--

In your case, I would set the path explicitly (as you're using `User` anyway):

```
<%= simple_form_for @user, url: user_path, method: :post html: {class: "user-form"} do |f| %>
```

Comment: Thanks - only reason I didn't default to this was because it then causes an issue with strong params in the controller. I can no longer specify `params.require(:user)...`. If I just have to hack it, no biggie. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: @AlecSanger this is an old question, but you can set `as: :user` and the entire form will post with the prefix `user[]` -- you can do it with what ever you want, `as: :foo` will post as `foo[]`

Answer (score 1):

In Rails 5, this can be solved with

```
<%= form_with scope: :user,
              model: @user,
              url: @user.id ? user_path(user) : users_path,
              local: true do |f| %>
  ...
  ...
<% end %>
```

The previous code instructs the FormBuilder to fill in the fields with the @user attributes, but it also instructs it to submit to the main route (not the inherited ones) and, with `scope:`, it also instructs it to name the fields using the `User` class name, not the child class names.

Comment: this is not work for, update/patch because the form use `POST`